# How to get temporary session token for accessing AWS ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I have put images in my AWS ECR. I want to pull image from edge device. If I use Access/Secret key in my edge device I can login to repository and access my images like below,

step-1: Add environment Variables

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=access-key
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret-key
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-1
```

step-2: login to elastic container registry using following command.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-southeast-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin repo-id.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
```

step-3: Pull image

```
 docker pull repo-id.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/image_name
```

These steps ensure me to pull image from ECR.

Now, **I don't want to store Access Key/ Secret on Edge Device**. I am looking for some Session key/ temporary keys to access ECR image without stroing Access/Secret on edge device. In this flow I can eliminate storing highly confidential data to edge device.

Any help would be appreciable.

Edit- 1:

one possible way is writing a Lambda function to generate password for ECR and protect the lambda with API Key in API Gateway. From Edge Device I will call the lambda function and get password to pull image.

Will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as your device is not located in AWS it will not be able to gain the benefit of having an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) directly attached to it (which solves the issue of non hard coded permissions).

You can however create an IAM role in AWS and then use the [STS service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html) to **assume the role from another IAM user/role** that has the permissions to [assume the role](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html). When you assume the role you are given temporary credentials to access the AWS services (you can decide the lifespan of the temporary credentials).

If you can find a method to copy these credentials to your local device you can then use them for the duration of their lifetime.

Comment: thanks for the response. Please take a look at updated question

Comment: Your solution would work, you'd want to keep it really locked down though. :)